# Visual Studio Code: How to force the "terminal" to actually display the remote terminal itself

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, terminal

I am sure there are a thousand duplicates, but I have not found them as what I have found involve the local terminal, or if about the remote terminal, it is assumed that the live terminal view already exists.  In my case the "terminal" aspect of the terminal does not yet exist within the terminal pane.

Setup:
Visual Studio Code installed on Win 10 doing remote development on a Linux based system.

Issue:
When I start Visual Studio Code, it automatically attaches itself to the remote system, as it should.

However, the terminal pane at the bottom of the editing window does ***NOT*** contain a "terminal", (*i.e.* with a prompt that I can type commands into). Instead it shows the output of VS Code's efforts to connect with the remote machine as shown below:

[image]

Which contains a lot of text:

```
93f51b4f790b: running
Acquiring lock on /home/pi/.vscode-server/bin/899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3/vscode-remote-lock.pi.899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3
Found existing installation at /home/pi/.vscode-server/bin/899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3...
Checking /home/pi/.vscode-server/.899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3.log and /home/pi/.vscode-server/.899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3.pid for a running server
Looking for server with pid: 4285
Starting server with command... /home/pi/.vscode-server/bin/899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3/server.sh --start-server --host=127.0.0.1 --enable-remote-auto-shutdown --port=0 --disable-telemetry   &> "/home/pi/.vscode-server/.899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3.log" < /dev/null
printenv:
    SHELL=/bin/bash
    PWD=/home/pi
    LOGNAME=pi
    XDG_SESSION_TYPE=tty
    LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/uv4l/uv4lext/armv6l/libuv4lext.so
    HOME=/home/pi
    LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    VSCODE_AGENT_FOLDER=/home/pi/.vscode-server
    SSH_CONNECTION=172.31.100.209 1025 172.31.100.20 22
    XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
    USER=pi
    SHLVL=0
    XDG_SESSION_ID=7
    XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
    SSH_CLIENT=172.31.100.209 1025 22
    PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games
    DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
    MAIL=/var/mail/pi
    _=/usr/bin/printenv
Spawned remote server: 22461
Waiting for server log...
Waiting for server log...
Waiting for server log...
Waiting for server log...
Waiting for server log...
Waiting for server log...
Waiting for server log...
Waiting for server log...
Waiting for server log...
Waiting for server log...
Waiting for server log...
Waiting for server log...
Waiting for server log...
Waiting for server log...
Waiting for server log...
Waiting for server log...
Waiting for server log...
 
*
* Reminder: You may only use this software with Visual Studio family products,
* as described in the license (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2077057)
*

93f51b4f790b: start
SSH_AUTH_SOCK====
DISPLAY====
webUiAccessToken====
listeningOn==40669==
osReleaseId==raspbian==
arch==armv7l==
tmpDir==/run/user/1000==
platform==linux==
unpackResult====
didLocalDownload==0==
downloadTime====
installTime====
extInstallTime====
serverStartTime==1088==
connectionToken==c996da7e-f0ac-4ecf-b214-07c49b988569==
93f51b4f790b: end
```

There is no terminal prompt, nor is there any way to type commands.

(IMHO this should be in the "OUTPUT" window instead of the terminal window.)

If I open a python file and execute it, this window magically changes into a real-live terminal window that I can use.

Just for that reason, I created a tiny Python program just to force the terminal window to be a ***terminal*** window:

```
# Open the terminal window
# A butt-ugly hack to force the VS Code terminal to be a terminal

print("Yippee! a terminal window!")
```

After I run it, my terminal window is a real terminal window.  This is an UGLY hack that I am sure there's a way around.

My question:
How do I make my terminal into a real, live, honest-to-Linux ***terminal*** without having to run something?

Thanks!

Comment: @Philippe That worked.  Visual Studio Code is such a "rich" environment, it's easy to overlook what might be obvious to others.  Can you post this as an answer so that I can accept it for you?  It's a great answer and you should get credit for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you click `Terminal` then `New Terminal`, you should get a fresh terminal inside remote environment.

Comment: That, and (as it turns out), clicking the "+", creates a real, interactive terminal. Executing something creates a terminal labeled "Python" and either of the two other methods creates a terminal labeled "bash". The original so-called "terminal" is labeled "install". This then asks the musical question: "Why is the "default" terminal on open a status window of some kind instead of an actual terminal?" You would think that an output-only stream like that would be named something else, or would be in a different category under "output".